# How to get the relative Uri of a filename (xaml) by it's Type?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have the Type of a XAML view.
I want to navigate to it passing a URI as its location just like you do when in Windows 8 Store Apps.

Basically, convert a Type to a relative URI to the root of the application.

Is it possible to do this in Windows Phone 7.5/8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type navigation in Windows Phone 8 (or earlier) is not supported.

For Windows 8 apps, a mapping class called XamlTypeInfoProvider is generated by the build process (you can find the file inside the `obj` folder after the build), and it's this file that allows for type navigation in Windows 8.

I suggest you create a custom Attribute and associate it with the class files, specifying the Xaml file associated, or just infer the Xaml file from the Type name (like Caliburn.Micro does!)